# ManyToOne referenced entities not exist in JSON Response when returning PagedResource

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, jackson2

When I return a `Page<Entity>` from a method inside my `@RestController` class, all fields of `Entity` both referenced via `@OneToXXX` and `@ManyToXXX` take place in the returned JSON object. But when I switched the return type to `PagedResource` (to be able to add links to the response), `@ManyToXXX` fields are not included at all.

Here is the method in question:

```
@GetMapping("/fetch")
public PagedResources getResults(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {

        Page<ParentClass> page = myRepository.findAll(pageable);

        PagedResources pagedResources = assembler.toResource(page, myResourceAssembler);

        return pagedResources;
}
```

Here is the resource assembler: it's `@Autowired` in the MyController's body.

**MyResourceAssembler**

```
@Component
public class MyResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<ParentClass, Resource> {
    public MyResourceAssembler() { super(MyController.class, Resource.class); }

    @Override
    public Resource toResource(ParentClass obj) {

        return new Resource<>(obj,
                linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class).getResults(obj.getId())).withRel("edit"),
    }
}
```

Here are the basic class definitions:

**ParentClass**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_table", catalog = "myDB")
public class ParentClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_class", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private OtherClass otherClass;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
    private SampleField1 sampleField1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<SampleField2> sampleField2;

}
```

**SampleField1** *OneToXXX*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample_table_1", catalog = "myDB")
public class SampleField1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="some_field")
    String someField;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sample_field_1", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference //to avoid infinite recursion
    private ParentClass parent;
}
```

**OtherClass** *ManyToOne*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "other_table", catalog = "myDB")
public class OtherClass  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="some_other_field")
    String someOtherField;

    // I don't need any reference to ParentClass here.
}
```

To add further detail to the issue here is the logging output of  `changeProperties()` method  inside `PersistentEntityJackson2Module` class:

```
s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Assigning nested entity serializer for @javax.persistence.OneToOne(..) com.project.SampleField1 com.project.model.ParentClass.sampleField1
s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Assigning nested entity serializer for @javax.persistence.OneToMany(..)  com.project.SampleField2 com.project.model.ParentClass.sampleField2
// .... omitted other lines for brevity
```

the resulting JSON is :

```
{
   "_embedded":{
      "parentClasses":[
         {
            "id":1,
            // <-- There is no field for otherClass !
            "sampleField1":{
               "id":1,
               "sampleField":"blabla"
            },
            "sampleField2":[ ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "links":[

   ]
}
```

As it can be seen above, `OneToXXX` fields are being taken to be serialized but no output for the `ManyToOne` fields like 
`Assigning nested entity serializer for @javax.persistence.ManyToOne ... com.my.OtherClass ...` and therefore those aren't existed in the response JSON.

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737500/spring-data-rest-manytoone-field-is-not-coming-in-json), `@ManyToXXX` referenced entities are appended as links to the JSON response. But that's not an acceptable solution for me since I have a different planning of consumption in my mind for the rest client.

Bottomline, **I'd like to have my `ManyToOne`  referenced entities in my JSON Response returned from `getResults()` method**.

Anything I can provide just ask in the comments.

Comment: When you debug you're code, are you seeing `otherClass` populated correctly?

Comment: Of course, `otherClass` gets populated perfectly and if I were to return just `Page<ParentClass>`, the `otherClass` is contained in the response. But I need to return `PagedResource` to benefit HATEOAS features.

Comment: what is your `resourceAssembler` doing?  Can you share that code?

Comment: done. check the edited question

Comment: Have you wrapped your ResourceAssembler in a try/catch to see if anything is blowing up?  This is very strange behavior

Comment: Yes I did. There's no exception thrown in the body.

Answer (score 2):

Return Entity in responses is not the best way, because usually clients dont need whole set of data. Also, if Entities has links for each other, it will cause StackoverflowException on serialization tries. Use DTO for responses. At least it will help you to determine where is the problem - serialization, or fetching from database. Anyway it is more proper way for serving data to clients.

By the way, check getter and setter for otherClass in your ParentClass :) If threre is no getter and setter, thats will be reason of your issue.

Also, take a look into OtherClass for default empty constructor. If it hasn't present in there, you should add it.

Comment: I know that returning entity was not the best way by experience these days :) Yet there's quite an accumulated code base shared by multiple developers, so changing to DTO is my last resort to say the least. About the suggestions; both getter/setter pairs and constructors do exist in respective entities. Let me gently remind you the said entities are in the JSON Response when I am returning `Page<ParentClass>`, it's just not there when the return type is `PagedResource`. And the reason I picked `PagedResource` over `Page<T>` is that I can add useful links to the `Resource`s.

Comment: I am beginning to think that `PagedResource`s is not mapping the  `ManyToXXX` entities into JSON *at all*. If only I could find a proof, I will abandon my approach right away.

Comment: @dashboard you could try DTO in this case at least for serialization debug, don't commit it to your repo (with lambdas it's pretty quick). I think that it's better than debug PageResourse, but this is the another option. Just try and share results, it's interesting. I'm not sure that the reason of issue is ManyToX annotations.